# What do "bundle" and "shape" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I find two verbs in this sentence from a [sports site](https://www.si.com/soccer/2018/04/12/heartbroken-gianluigi-buffon-lambasts-murderer-michael-oliver-last-minute-penalty-call) elusive in meaning.

> But there was to be no fairytale, with Oliver blowing for a penalty after adjudging Mehdi Benatia to have **bundled over** Lucas Vazquez as the winger **shaped to score** from point plank range.

Having checked Google, **bundle over** doesn't appear to be idiomatic. **Bundle** as a verb means *rush, hurry*. But what does it mean here? Is it a non-idiomatic usage?

Also **shaped to score** supposedly means *was about to score*, but I can't find this usage in dictionaries either. It also appears to be quite different from **shape up to be**.

Comment: I think it should read "point blank" not "point plank".

Comment: It's possible the author is not a native speaker. My guess, someone from Scandinavia.

Comment: Be aware this is all soccer/football *jargon*.  Many in the U.S. would have no idea what was going on in this sentence.

Comment: We watch a lot of British Premier League football in these here parts.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo， the phrase "in these here parts" looks strange to me. Can you help to explain it a bit?

Comment: @Andrew Very true. I thought it was cricket jargon until I followed the link. (I'm from the US.)

Comment: @dan: "these here parts" is regional dialect, used by so-called "hillbillies" and "rednecks".  (Those are colloquial pejorative terms for relatively uneducated US southerners, backwoods, rural, and small-town dwellers.) The phrase means "around here" or "in this locality".  "here" is regarded as non-standard when used in tandem with the demonstrative and a noun: this here dog can hunt; these here dogs can hunt.

Comment: @miltonaut  quick tip:  If they talk about *bowlers, batters*, and *overs* it's cricket.  If they talk about *wingers, strikers*, or *corners*, it's soccer.  However, none of this is nearly as difficult as explaining American football to a non-native.  :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Bundle", as a verb, can mean [Push or shove](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bundle), in a hurried or untidy way.  Mehdi pushed Lucas over, or tripped him up in some way.

"Shaped to score" looks like an expression invented by this journalist. I assume it means "got into a shape to shoot for the goal" so he balanced himself and prepared to kick the ball.

The general meaning is clear.  One player fouled another, just as the second player was going to shoot.